# How to enforce rigid body constraints while editing?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm designing some toy puzzles using Blender. For example, here is the classical puzzle with two rings each having a small opening, where both openings have to be aligned in order to separate them:

[image: Animation as played by Alt+A: the two rings do not get past each other]

I would like to temporarily enable constraints while editing the scene, so that I can "jiggle" the objects around, using the grab <kbd>G</kbd> and rotate <kbd>R</kbd>, and check that the puzzle works as expected, just like I would do with a 3D-printed object for example. The problem is that objects pass through each other when editing:

[image: When moving the ring with G, it passes through the other one]

I can somewhat manage to get the behaviour I want by creating a dummy object, attaching it to the ring with a `Fixed` constraint, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to start the animation, and moving the dummy object, but this is rather impractical as the dummy object starts falling if you don't grab <kbd>G</kbd> it quickly enough etc.

[image: When moving the dummy object, the ring collides with the other, as expected, but this is impractical to use]

Is there a way to enable user control of an object's position and rotation, while enforcing rigid body constraints? I am a programmer, but I am not familiar *at all* with Blender's API, so if the solution involves Python please be include a couple of pointers to the relevant API docs.

[image]